# How to use 'db.query' for the NodeJS AWS-SDK for DynamoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb

Folks,
  I have the following table:

```
  hashKey (model):   RangeKey (make):
  mustang            ford
  f150               ford
  malibu             chevy
  ...
```

What I would like to do is search and return all Ford models, ie:

```
var params = {
        TableName : 'models',
        IndexName : 'make-index',
        KeyConditions : 
        {
            "make" : 
            {
                "AttributeValueList" : [
                {
                    "S" : 'ford'
                }
                ],
                "ComparisonOperator" : "EQ"
            }
        },
    }
    db.query(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log (err)
            callback(err, null)
        } else {
            callback(null, data.Items)
        }
    });
```

What am I doing wrong? :)  Thanks!

Comment: I am trying to avoid the way i know how to build this table... ie 

`entry` `make` `model`

If i make hashkey a known string, then i can certainly query.  but this seems like a non-aws way of using dynamo

Answer (score 2):

Have you set up a global secondary index with `make` as the hash key of the index?  Your query is telling DynamoDB to use an index named `make-index`, but it's not clear from your question whether that index exists.

The only way to use the `Query` operation in DynamoDB is using an `EQ` operator on a hash key.  That could be on the hash key on the table, or a hash key on a global secondary index, but there's no way (without a global secondary index) to construct a query that says "give me all the items whose range key is `ford`." If you have a global secondary index set up with `make` as the hash key, then you could perform the query you've described.

Unfortunately, indexes can only be created when the table is created.  If you don't have a global secondary index on the `make` item, then you could accomplish it with a `Scan` operation, but it won't be as performant as a `Query`.

Answer (score -1):

You can make global secondary indexes after a table is made.  Go to the amazon aws dynamodb console, click on a table and click "create index."

You can find the amazon aws console by typing "amazon aws" into google.